# Disabling UIScrollView gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, swift, gesture

I've created a custom scrollview class that uses two child views which can be scrolled (with paging enabled) to have either view currently on the screen.

What I would like to do is changing it so that the second view only scrolls in when a specific button is tapped. So the user should not be allowed to scroll in the second view with a drag gesture.

How can I temporarily disabled the drag gesture on the scroll view? (Temporarily because when the second view has been scrolled in, it should be reactivated so the user can drag that view out of the screen).

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.myscrollview.scrollEnabled = NO;`

Comment: Works in my case, thanks! Although it would be nice to know how to do this with Gesture Recognizers since the second view can optionally be offset so that a part of it is visible on the screen initially and it would be great if only that part can be dragged initially to open the second view.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do it with Gestures but perhaps you can just handle the `scrollViewDidScroll` event and only   `if(scrollView.contentOffset.y > 10)` do you disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without coding like this:

In the attribute inspector of Scrollview there is scrolling property. Just uncheck the scrolling enabled and it will surely work!See the image.

[image]